# What to use for SQL Server instead of "Key"?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have a script of MySQL queries that I use and that work.

I'm trying to execute the same queries in Microsoft SQL server and there's one thing I don't understand.

MySql uses "key" to define a key made up of different fields.

What is the way to do the same thing in SQL Server?

Thanks!

-Adeena

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a primary key that consists of multiple columns in TSQL (SQL server's query language)

```
ALTER TABLE product
    ADD CONSTRAINT prim_prod PRIMARY KEY(product_foo, product_bar)
```

If you use SQL Server Management studio, you can also achieve this via "Modify Table".

Comment: hmm... I thought there could only be one primary key?

Comment: There is only one primary key, but it can consist of multiple columns.  That way product_foo and product_bar needn't be unique on their own, but considered together they must be unique.

I always prefer single field primary keys, but this is possible.

Comment: yes, only one primary key is allowed. But you can start with a table WITHOUT primary key.

Comment: This type of primary key is called a composite key, here is a nice blog post describing the various types of PK you could implement. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the keyword `KEY` is simply a synonym for `INDEX`.  The following two are equivalent:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ctime  DATETIME,
  KEY ctkey (ctime)
);

CREATE TABLE foo (
  id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ctime  DATETIME,
  INDEX ctidx (ctime)
);
```

In Microsoft SQL Server, the closest equivalent is `INDEX`.  As far as I can tell, to create an index on a column in Microsoft SQL Server, you use `CREATE INDEX`.  You can also create constraints that build indexes as part of a `CREATE TABLE` statement, but if you just need an index, use `CREATE INDEX`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id     BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ctime  DATETIME
);

CREATE INDEX ctidx ON foo(ctime);
```

See also documentation on [`CREATE INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(SQL.90).aspx).